# Why do we have these probability functions for this Markov Chain?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

The following shows one of the questions we were given in lectures a while back:

[image: question]

We have been given the following solutions to this question:

[image: sols]

I'm rather confused by these. Take, for example, the probability function $f_{11}^{n}$. In the solutions, it says that this is equal to
$$
f_{11}^{n} = \begin{cases} 0.5 \quad \text{ if } n=2 \\ 0.5 \quad \text{ if } n=3 \\ 0 \quad \text{ otherwise}  \end{cases}
$$
This implies that the probability of the process returning to state 1 in (for example) 4 moves is $0$. However, I can see that this probability is actually $0.25$, as it is given by the path $1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The simplest way to find the probability after $n$ steps is to calculate $n$th power of transition matrix. You have $n$=2,3 so it should be relatively easy compared to tracking them manually.

Comment: Computations for 4th power with Wolfram gives $f_{1,1}^{(4)}=0.75$

Comment: I think $f_{i,j}^{(n)}$ here are something else, they are equal to transition probabilities when their sum is less than $1$ and are set to $0$ afterwards. It seems you need to find the number $n$. Maybe something is said in the text above the actual problem 4 ?

Comment: Obviously, $f^{(n)}_{ij}$ is the probability starting from $i$ that the **first** visit to $j$ happens at time $n$ -- as your source most probably explains before the text of the exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the first visit.

$$f_{ij}^{(n)} = P(X_n = j,\: X_k \not = j, \: k=1,2,\ldots,n-1 \mid X_0 = i)$$

You can make two first revisits to $1$ by

$n=2: \:\:1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 1$

$n=3: \:\:1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1$

$$f_{ij}^{(n)} = \sum_{k \not = j} p_{ik} f_{kj}^{(n-1)} $$

Comment: Thank you. Does the notation $f_{ij}^(n)$ always refer to the first visit? What about $p_{ij}^(n)$? If so, what is the notation for the probability of it being in a certain state, if we do not care whether it is the first visit?

Comment: @user2910074 Yes, $f_{ij}^{(n)}$ is defined as the first visit. $p_{ij}^{(n)} = P(X_n = j \mid X_0 = i)$